# Getting the values of an attribute in XML using Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, tei

I am using Beautiful Soup to traverse some TEI XML that I've written for Peanuts comic strips. I'm trying to isolate certain features that are recorded in the `div` using the `@ana` attribute.

```
 <text>
      <body>
         <head><emph>Peanuts</emph>, <date when="1971-10-01">1 October 1971</date></head>
         
         <div type="panelGrp" xml:id="Peanuts1971-10-01" ana="#s-psych #s-outside">
            ...
         </div>
      </body>
   </text>
```

I can isolate this particular div (the only one in each document) using the following.

```
def make_soup(xmlfile):
    with open(xmlfile) as xml_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'lxml-xml')
        return soup

div = soup.find('div')
```

Where I am stuck, however, is accessing the contents of `@ana`. In this case, the output should be `#s-psych #s-outside`.

Comment: Since you are parsing an xml file, you will probably be better off using an xml parser like lxml instead of beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your function, but I think you can pick the answer from my mockup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("Peanats.html", 'r') as htm_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htm_file, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
    print(soup.div['ana']) # What you search for
```

Output:

```
#s-psych #s-outside
```